# Change the timeout setting of a GCP load balancer backend service

Tags: google-cloud-run, gcp-load-balancer

Is it possible to change the timeout setting of a GCP load balancer backend service (a cloud run)?
I tried with the command:

```
gcloud compute backend-services update my-cloudrun-backend-service --global --project my-project \
--timeout=600
```

and I got the error:

```
- Invalid value for field 'resource.timeoutSec': '600'. Timeout sec is not supported for a backend service with Serverless network endpoint groups.
```

I can't understand why this is fixed to 30s as mentioned in the docs.